# Building a Binary Search Tree from a file

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have a text file of lines in the format

```
2 0 0
7 0 0
4 1 1
10 0 0
9 0 1
8 1 1
```

These lines represent the data in a binary search tree where the first element is the node data, the second is whether or not a left child exists ( 0 if no, 1 if yes) and the third is whether or not a right child exists (0 if no, 1 if yes)

I have a class called "BinarySearchTree" which has the following initialization function

```
def __init__(self, value=None):
        # Initializes the tree with a value node, a left child and a right child
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
        self.height = 1
        self.value = value
```

I also have a stack class with the following "push" and "pop" functions:

```
def push(self, item):
    # Adds an item to the beginning of the stack
    ending = self.stack
    self.stack = [item] + [ending]

def pop(self):
    # Removes and returns the first element from the stack
    if self.isEmpty():
        return None
    top_element = self.stack[0]
    self.stack = self.stack[1:]
    return top_element
```

I am trying to create a binary search tree instance from the lines in the text file and using the stack class. So far I have:

```
def loadTreeFromFile(filename):
    binarySearchTree = stack.Stack()

    with open(filename) as file:
        # gets a list containing only the elements in the txt file
        for level in file.readlines():
            nodeInfo = level.rstrip().split()
            data, lc, rc = int(nodeInfo[0]), int(nodeInfo[1]), int(nodeInfo[2])
            print(data, lc, rc)
            if rc == 1:
                right_tree = binarySearchTree.pop()
            if lc == 1:
                left_tree = binarySearchTree.pop()
            newTree = BinarySearchTree(data)
            if rc == 1:
                newTree.rightChild = right_tree
            if lc == 1:
                newTree.leftChild = left_tree
            binarySearchTree.push(newTree)
    return newTree
```

I am running into the problem when I try to display the BST, I get `8: [[[<__main__.BinarySearchTree object at 0x1033e4390>, []]], 9: [None, 10: [None, None]]]` (I have a display function written for the BST class so this is not the problem) AND when I try to do anything with this newly created BST (such as get the depth, search it, etc), I get errors. Any help is much appreciated, thanks  .

Comment: I haven't fully grasped all you're doing.  I see one line that is suspect:  "self.stack = [item] + [ending]".  Seems you are wrapping the existing list into another level of list every time you add to it.  Shouldn't this be "self.stack = [item] + ending"?  Or just "self.stack = [item] + self.stack.

Comment: I think youre on to something, however when I do that I get an error "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list"

Comment: We can't solve your problem without seeing the rest of the code.